# What is the proper English for forcefully occupying tenders?

Tags: single-word-requests

In some places, when governments and local authorities [call for tenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_tender) from potential contractors for various projects, incoming tenders are physically delivered into a box where they are stored until the tender process is complete. In some parts of the world, tenders can be the root of rather serious and violent clashes (e.g., [in South Africa](http://www.heraldlive.co.za/news/2014/07/23/city-hamstrung-theft-tender-documents/) or [Bangladesh](http://www.thedailystar.net/news-detail-133594)).

Suppose in such a place one bidder physically occupies that tender box, preventing anyone else from dropping in any tenders of their own and thus making sure they themselves win the tender.

From a certain point of view it can be considered *tender theft*; but that’s quite a broad term, and I remember reading a specific term for this kind of ‘hogging’ the tender box itself in a newspaper once.

#### What is the proper English term for ‘tender box hogging’?

Comment: The term "tender-box" is unfamiliar to me as a native speaker of British English. Google isn't much help either, though it shows an image of what looks like a ballot box. This may be a term specific to English in your part of the world; you should probably define it rather than leaving us to guess.

Comment: Would 'holding to ransom' work?

Comment: The clarification makes it clear (more or less) what you meant by _tender-box_; but I still don't understand how anyone is supposed to be able to prevent someone else from bidding for a tender, short of using mafia techniques to threaten them not to, which is not generally an option in tender bidding where you don't know who the other bidders are.

Comment: **[Monopolization](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monopolization)**?

Comment: So in some countries tenders are literally delivered as documents in boxes and then left there to be stolen, it seems. Interesting. I'd never heard of that before, but in such a scenario it would make sense for someone to try to ‘hog’ the tender box. Never heard of a name for it, though.

Comment: I’ve reworded and clarified the question to give a bit more background for those not familiar with the situation in which this may occur; please feel free to improve further if needed.

Comment: The concept is basically unknown in the US, and so there would be no idiomatic term for it.  Usually corruption in the US is more subtle than this.

Comment: The OP's scenario is a clear offence, a 'breach of the peace' under most Common Law jurisdictions. It may be called something else or rendered a statutory misdemeanor in US federal or state law. Evidently the tender box is just as likely to become a tinder box!

Comment: This is called *strong arm tactics*. There is the phrasal verb *muscled out*